# Indian ATMs limits and charges for foreign cards

Tags: india, fees-and-charges, atms

I am travelling to India and generally when I travel I don't exchange money. I just have a couple of UK bank accounts with banks that do not charge anything when withdrawing money abroad, passing the exchange rates of  MasterCard or Visa with no extra fees.

However, in some cases the ATMs I withdraw money from charge a fee for foreign cards. The last one I got money from, charged 236 rupees on a Rp10000 withdrawal, so the fee was 2.36%.

Does someone know the banks with the highest daily withdrawal limits and the lowest fees for foreign cards in Rajasthan and Uttarakhand, so that the fee as a percentage is minimized?